# How to use Python to map bytes to C struct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I have a nested C struct (size is very large) and bytes

```
// In C:
struct example1 {
  int val1;
  int val2;
  int val3;
  int val4; 
  char c1;
  char c2;
  enum example2 e1;
  union example3 u1;
  struct example4 s1;
  ...
  ....
  ....
};
```

```
# In python
example1_bytes = b'\x08\x09\x0a\x0b...........'
```

How to map the bytes to C struct and access the member?

Comment: I want to use python to process

Comment: have you tried writing the code in `python`?

Comment: Yes, but the structure is very complex, I don't know how to process

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] for what you need? The usual answer is the ``struct`` module, but it looks like you need more than that – e.g. nested ``union``s and ``struct``s.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map those bytes in python, you can use `struct.unpack()`

The official [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) will tell you how to write the format argument to map C types.

Example:

```
import struct
mapped_bytes = struct.unpack(">ii", example_bytes)
```

Comment: ``struct`` will only work for a flat collection of primitive types. It's not suitable for nested ``struct``s or ``union``s.

Comment: I don't have much experience with unpacking, so I might be wrong, but as long as they know what those nested `struct`s and `union`s contain, shouldn't it be possible to use `unpack()` anyway?

Comment: For nested ``struct``s, the problem is that one loses all nesting. For a ``union``, one has to separately unpack all cases. Both could be recovered manually, but it's a lot more complex than just using the ``struct`` module.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I knew you would lose the nesting, I just wanted to make sure it was actually possible at all.

Comment: You can use the ctypes module to do just about anything with C structures.  You can nest them, declare arrays, etc.